# Prevent absolute positioned element from dividing a word

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Is there a way to prevent an empty absolute positioned block element from causing a word-wrap?

My html looks something like

```
    some other words here. 
My_very_long_text<div style='position: absolute; width:20px; height:20px; background-color:green;'></div>_This_should_Not_be_on_next_line
```

And the problem is that the browser will do a word-wrap (Move text to the next line) after the My_very_long_text so that _This_should_Not_be_on_next_line
does start on the next line. Is there any way to prevent that?

The solution would in this case insert the line-break "some other words here" so the text should be output as if the absolute positioned div was not there.

**Added:**
I have added a test case which shows the problem. (Tested in firefox 16.0.1 where it break the line after "My_very_long_text". If I start firebug and remove the absolute positioned span then the text break as expected. But I just tested it in chrome and there it works as expected, so maybe this is just a firefox bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style='width:600px; background-color:red; position:relative; font-size:14px; font-family: monospace'>
so much better to test it this way My_very_long_text<span style='position: absolute; width:20px; height:20px; background-color:green;'></span>_This_should_Not_be_on_next_line
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as bookcasey comments, that should not be the problem, can you post the whole page to check your problem?

Comment: Agree. It may just be a firefox bug

Answer (score 1):

An absolutely position element has no effect on the regular flow of the document. Absolutely positioned elements don't 'push' other elements around, they exist on their own plane. Something else is causing the word wrap.

Comment: Se updated case which shows the problem. A bug in firefox pehaps?

Comment: unfortunately I can't agree. I mean they SHOULD act this way, but they don't, at least not on Webkit. I have this problem right now: a checkbox and an associated label. Upon submit I validate, and an absolute positioned div appears in the DOM after the checkbox, before the label, causing the label to go to next line. I've tried float:left, I've tried inline-block, and it still does that. When the absolute div is hidden (not removed) it goes back to normal. And when it validates again, the div reappears, but does not cause the label to go to the next line. This bug is old, across many versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the CSS overflow or word-wrap property.

Hide the overflow:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Scroll the overflow:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Also scrolls the overflow, more common method:

```
overflow:auto;
```

OR, use the word-wrap to break the words at a specified area.

This will break the words:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

This wraps normally:

```
word-wrap:normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and only solution I found is to add a `span` with `white-space: nowrap` around the problematic word.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div style='width:600px; background-color:red; position:relative; font-size:14px; font-family: monospace'>
    so much better to test it this way <span style='white-space: nowrap'>My_very_long_text<span style='position: absolute; width:20px; height:20px; background-color:green;'></span>_This_should_Not_be_on_next_line<span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```